# How do I Display date on Aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, webforms

I am using asp.net webforms for the first time and am trying to display the current date in the following form: Friday, July 13

```
<h3>Suggested reading for <% DateTime.Now.ToString(); %></h3>
```

However, this only displays

```
Suggested reading for
```

on my page.

I don't know if this helps, but here is some surrounding code:

```
<%@ Page Title="Register" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="Fake_Coupon_Site.Account.Register" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <hgroup class="title">
        <h1><%: Title %>.</h1>
        <h2>Use the form below to create a new account.</h2>
        <h3>Suggested reading for <% DateTime.Now.ToString(); %></h3>
    </hgroup>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
<h3>Suggested reading for <%= DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, MMMM dd") %></h3>
```

Comment: It's just a different type of code block, '<%= ... %>' is the same as writing '<% Response.Write(...) %>', here is some more info on the different code blocks and what they do: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112

Comment: You also may want to add the culture to the ToString method.